# q/KDB+ based on condition left join on multiple columns

Tags: kdb

Order Table

| Sym | platform | userID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| MSFT | Reuters | user1 |
| AAPL | wallstreet | boris |
| MSFT | Reuters | user2 |
| AAPL | wallstreet | bill |
| IBM | other | 6723 |

System table

| name | platform | userID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| jobs | Reuters | user1 |
| bill | wallstreet | 65432 |
| steve | Reuters | user2 |
| boris | wallstreet | 6543212 |

query
`` data:orders lj `userID xkey select from system; ``
Am struck to join 2 columns based on condition
if platform is "Reuters" left join with userID on system table and if platform is "wallstreet" use name column to join in a one go

Comment: Can you add an expected output? It'll help anyone trying to answer the question.

Comment: In addition to Thomas' comment please consider posting the q code necessary to generate the tables. e.g. ```order:([]Sym:`a`b;platform:`c`d;userID:`e`f)```

Comment: Also, you can't have a table called `system` as this is a reserved word in q. `select from system` will give you an error.

Comment: How do you join on 'name' if the **Order Table** does not contain such column?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a temporary column to join on.

Which has either contents of `userID` or `name` depending on your rule:

```
data:delete tmp from (update tmp:userID from orders) lj 
 `tmp xkey update tmp:?[platform=`Reuters;userID;name] from system;
```